# Update database table records based on array of data

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an array of objects like this:

[ {User_ID: 1, Source_ID: 1}, {User_ID: 1, Source_ID: 2}]

And my access table design:

| AccessID | User_ID | Source_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

If I want to update the access records for User_ID = 1 to [ {User_ID: 1, Source_ID: 1}, {User_ID: 1, Source_ID: 3} ]

How can I Remove the access record "User_ID = 1, Source_ID = 2" And Insert the access record "User_ID = 1, Source_ID = 3", but keep the "User_ID = 1, Source_ID = 1" record.

Using stored procedure?

What I have so far:

C#:

```
...Create the DB Command and add parameter "Source_ID"..

foreach (var SourceID in user.SourceAccess)
{
  dBCall1.GetCommand().Parameters["Source_ID"].Value = SourceID;
  dBCall1.ExecuteNonQuery;
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUserSourceAccess]
    @UserID INT,
    @SourceID INT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [UserSourceAccess] WHERE [User_ID] = @UserID AND Source_ID = @SourceID)
    INSERT INTO UserSourceAccess
    ( UserID, SourceID ) VALUES ( @UserID, @SourceID )
...
```

Comment: How do you decide you want to keep source 1 but not 2? If the AccessID were part of the array you could do an upsert/merge operation easily enough.

Comment: Maybe you can use `SQL Merge` statement. WHEN Matched do Operation 1 WHEN Not Matched do Operation 2

Comment: The Access_ID was not part of the array and it is the primary key for Access table (Used to keep track the users accesses to sources). I want to be able to switch the users source access (A user could have 1 - many sources accesses)

Comment: In SQL Server you can create temp table and insert your array data there. From that table you can do compare of records and delete/insert operations can be done.

Comment: By what logic would you keep rows 3 and 4, given they are not in you array? Is it actually that you have a list of `Source_ID` that you need to match, but only for a single `User_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying to do, is that you need to be able to compare a full list of `Source_ID` per user, and insert or delete as necessary.

For this to work, you need the procedure to have the full list to compare, so you are best off passing in a Table-Valued Parameter. I usually keep a few standard table-types for this purpose:

```sql
CREATE TYPE IdList (Id int PRIMARY KEY);

GO
```

Then you need to do a partial `MERGE`: in other words do *not* `MERGE` the full table, because then any *other* users will get all their rows deleted. Instead pre-filter the target table with a CTE. We can then `MERGE` against the CTE, comparing against the table parameter.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateUserSourceAccess]
    @UserID int,
    @SourceIDs dbo.IdList
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH t AS (
    SELECT t.AccessID, t.User_ID, t.Source_ID
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE t.User_ID = @UserID
)
MERGE INTO t
USING @SourceIDs s
  ON s.Id = t.Source_ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
  THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
  THEN INSERT (User_ID, Source_ID)
       VALUES (@UserID, s.val)
;

GO
```

You can call it from C# like this

```cs
using(var comm = new SqlCommand("UpdateUserSourceAccess", yourConnection))
{
    var table = new DataTable { Columns = { { "Id", typeof(int) } } };
    foreach (var SourceID in user.SourceAccess)
        table.Rows.Add(SourceID);

    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SourceIDs", SqlDbType.Structured)
    {
        TypeName = "dbo.IdList",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        Value = table
    });
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery;
}
```